# Dependency Injection & Testing

Tags: go

I'm working on a small Go application that's basically a wrapper for various password stores (Ansible Vault, Hashicorp Vault, Chef Vault, etc).  The idea is: In my various provisioning scripts, I can use my Go wrapper to grab secrets and if we decide to switch password stores behind the scenes, all of the interfaces don't need to be updated across my projects.

I'm trying to setup proper tests for this application, and in doing so, am trying to figure out the best way to to inject my dependencies.

For example, lets say the project is called `secrets`.  And one of my implementations is `ansible`.  And the ansible implementation needs its own `parser` and needs to open its own `connection` to the ansible vault, to retrieve the data.

So I might have the following:

```
package secrets

type PasswordStore interface {
    GetKey(key string) (string, error)
}

func New(backend string, config map[string]interface{}) (PasswordStore, error) {
    switch backend {
    case "ansible":
        return ansible.New(config)
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Password store '%s' not supported.", backend)
    }
}


package ansible


type Connection interface {
    open() (string, error)
}

type Ansible struct {
    connection Connection
    contents   map[string]string
}

func New(c map[string]interface{}) (*Ansible, error) {
    conn, err := NewConnection(c["ansible_path"].(string))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // open connection, parse, etc...   

    a := &Ansible{
        connection: conn,
        contents:   parsedData,
    }

    return a, nil
}
```

So this seems nice because the `secrets` package doesn't need knowledge of the `ansible` package dependencies (connection), and the factory just new's up the instance with some config data.  However, if I need to mock the `connection` that Ansible receives, there doesn't seem to be a good way to do this (unless that config map had a connection option called `mock`)

The other option is to abandon the factory, and just assemble all the dependencies from the `secrets` package, like:

```
package secrets

type PasswordStore interface {
    GetKey(key string) (string, error)
}

func New(backend string, config map[string]interface{}) (PasswordStore, error) {
    switch backend {
    case "ansible":
        return ansible.New(AnsibleConnection{}, config)
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Password store '%s' not supported.", backend)
    }
}

package ansible


// same as before in this file, but with injected dependency ...

func New(connect Connection, c map[string]interface{}) (*Ansible, error) {
    conn, err := connect.NewConnection(c["ansible_path"].(string))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // open connection, parse, etc...   

    a := &Ansible{
        connection: conn,
        contents:   parsedData,
    }

    return a, nil
}
```

Now the dependency is injected, but it seems like `secrets` needs to have knowledge of every dependency for every implementation.

Is there a more logical way to structure this so that `secrets` knows less?  Or is it typical for the top level package to be orchestrating everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What decides what the backend is? That should help guide you. I've done something similar with support for multiple databases on a project, and what I did was basically:

- `config` package reads in config file, which determines what backend is being used
- `store` package offers the generic interface and has a function that takes a config, and returns an implementation
- `server` package references only the interface
- `main` package reads the config, passes it to the factory function in `store`, then injects the result into the server on creation

So when I create my server (which actually uses the data store), I pass the config to the factory function in `store`, which returns an interface, and then inject that into the server. The only thing that has to know about the different concrete implementations is the same package that exposes the interface and factory; the `server`, `config`, and `main` packages see it as a black box.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Yes, I have a config map in the ansible.new() method which would have all the config data (presumably pulled from a file or something).  My question is: if you want to mock something going into the `store`, do you have a configuration key that provides a mock?

Comment: No, I skip the factory function entirely and pass my stub/mock directly to the unit under test.

Comment: @Adrian and what is inside `store` factory function? Did you put just conditions to returning proper interface depending on your config? Or there is a more advanced solution?

Comment: @SergeyPodgornyy correct, depending on the config; that is the purpose of configuration, to control behavior at runtime. I don't see a need for a "more advanced" solution.

Comment: @Adrian I thought there is some flexible solution. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @SergeyPodgornyy more flexible how? A factory function can have any logic you need and return any implementation you need, I'm not sure how it could be more flexible than that.

Comment: @Adrian sorry, probably flexible is a wrong word. I meant more configurable, avoiding writing long function, if `dev`, then build this implementation, if `staging`, then build another, and if `production`, then build second. 
It will look quite big and messy. So I am interested if there is a simpler solution to do that?

Comment: I've never run into a scenario where each environment wanted different *implementations* rather than simply different *configurations*, but I would definitely not base it on "if dev do X", but rather have the configuration indicate what implementation to use (e.g. `"driver": "postgres"` for a database or `"mq":"sqs"` for a message queue).